# How to disable gzip compression for text/html on Nginx servers?

Tags: nginx, gzip

My gzip config looks like this:

```
gzip  on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 1500;
gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype;
```

You will notice that `text/html` is not in my list of types, but Chrome is showing that it's gzipped anyway. [This article](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/) says that `text/html` is enabled by default. I want to disable it for [security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29109104/65387). How can I do that?

Comment: nginx don't use ssl-level compression

Comment: @Deadooshka Are you saying that nginx doesn't perform secure enough compression to use with SSL? Or that I shouldn't use compression over SSL connections with nginx?

Comment: ssl compression is about the "crime" vulnerability. Apache has `SSLCompression` directive but nginx don't use it on a build level. Although gzip itself is safe, see also "breach" vulnerability.

Comment: If nginx performs HTTP-level compression, then according to [this post](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/19914/5862) I should be safe against the CRIME vulnerability. It appears I *am* vulnerable to BREACH according to [this site](http://breachattack.com/) though -- but still, they can only decipher the given request... if only I could disable text/html compression.

Comment: it can be disabled in some context like `location \.html$ {gzip off;}` or `if()` in another location. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html):

> Responses with the “`text/html`” type are always compressed.

You can disable gzip entirely:

```
gzip off
```

[This article](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html) suggests disabling SSL compression entirely.

Comment: Is it really necessary to disable it for non-sensitive data? We've got oodles for CSS and JS I'd like to keep compressed. I'm starting to dislike all the stuff nginx does for you automatically.

Comment: Yep, it's annoying. I don't know any way around it with nginx, unless you want to dive into the source code and write a patch.