# How to add Content-Length header to cached files on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, caching, http-content-length

I'm using using Nginx as Reverse Proxy and Caching the proxied response from my upstream server.

So, I need to add a Content-Length header to this cached files before sending to my client.

I've tried adding the **$upstream_response_length** variable to location directive, but it doesn't work.

```
location /files/ {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_buffering on;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    ##PROXY CACHE CONFIG

    proxy_cache my_cache;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid any 30m;
    add_header Content-Length $upstream_response_length;

    proxy_pass http://upstream_server;

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/529621/forcing-nginx-to-send-content-length-headers-when-serving-static-files-with-gzip

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779960/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-for-text-html

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,216427,216442#msg-216442):

> nginx removes Content-Length header (and uses chunked if possible)
>   if resulting length after processing isn't known. This happens
>   e.g. if you use gzip, ssi, sub or addition modules.

So it's likely you're using one of those.

I believe that NGINX "knows" content length of cached pages, so it should send `Content-Length` for them by default, *unless* you use those modules.

Comment: This is accurate, and keep in mind gzip affects primarily `text/html` content so if you want to have `Content-Length` for e.g. ETags or whatever to work properly on HTML files, then you have to disable gzip on your Nginx server and/or CDN.